# Makefile variable

Tags: makefile

Hi I have `makefile` with variable, somethings like this :

```
NDK     := ~/Application/Android/SDK/NDK
ARCH    := arm
ifeq ($(ARCH),arm)
//..etc..
endif
```

but when I try to `makefile` i get this error :

```
: NDK: command not found
: ARCH: command not found
: syntax error near unexpected token `$(ARCH),arm'
```

I'm on ubuntu
that is variable I know, but why i got error for them ? whats wrong anf how to fix ?
I'm new in ubuntu!

Comment: What do you mean by 'I try to makefile'. Don't you use 'make'?

Comment: @robsn no i don't use from `make` , here you can see my `makefile` : `https://github.com/mtmiller/openconnect/blob/master/android/Makefile`

Comment: You have to use `make`. You can't run a makefile on its own. A makefile is just instructions for `make`. Please see jotik's answer.

Comment: @robsn Yes you can. See my answer :)

Comment: @jotik well, ok. In this case it runs `make` implicitly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to run the `./makefile` as an executable. But you should instead run it using `make`. For example:

```
make -f makefile
```

or just

```
make
```

if your makefile is properly named `makefile` or `Makefile`.

In case you really need to execute the makefile directly, see [this StackOverflow question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7123241/3919155) about how to add a proper shebang to the makefile.

Comment: Thanks, you right, sorry for bad question and thanks for your answer