# Executable Makefile that runs in a specific directory

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make, executable, gnu

*What I try to achieve*:

- making a makefile executable using a shebang
- making it switch to a certain directory beforehands, so it is callable from any where

*What I have*:

/docker/images/Makefile (with executable flag):

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

default: ...
...
```

I can do

```
cd /docker/images
./Makefile
```

However, *what I would like to be able to do*:

```
cd /somewhere/else
/docker/images/Makefile
```

*What I tried*:

`man make` states, that I can set a `--directoy <dir>` param.
However, the shebang `#!/usr/bin/make --directory=/docker/images -f`, does not work:

```
$ cd /somewhere/else
$ /docker/images/Makefile
make: *** =/docker/images -f: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden.  Schluss.
```

(File or dir not found)

Any guesses?
I'm on Devuan ASCII with GNU Make 4.1

I've seen the [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123241/makefile-as-an-executable-script-with-shebang) which does not address my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. Use `/usr/bin/env` with `-S` option, which is exactly meant for splitting parameters on the shebang line.

```
$ cat Makefile
#!/usr/bin/env -S make -C /docker/images -f
all:
        echo Foo
```

Output:

```
$ /docker/images/Makefile
make: Entering directory '/docker/images'
echo Foo
Foo
make: Leaving directory '/docker/images'
```

Comment: Heck. This would be the accepted answer, if my env would support it:
`/usr/bin/env --version`: env (GNU coreutils) 8.26  

Spoiler: it does not. (Only -i, -0, -u)

Comment: Ah, makes sense. It's a 8.30 feature, available in stock Ubuntu 20.04 LTS at least.

Answer (score 0):

When we put `#!/usr/bin/make --directory=/docker/images -f`

and run `/docker/images/Makefile`

It's equivalent to run :

```
/usr/bin/make "--directory=/docker/images -f" /docker/images/Makefile
```

One solution is to delegate to second line :

```
#!/home/debian/bin/run_second_line
# /usr/bin/make --directory=/docker/images -f

default: ...
...
```

In /home/debian/bin/run_second_line:

```
#!/bin/bash
get_second_line=$(awk 'NR == 2{print}' "$1")
exec bash -c "${get_second_line#?} $1"
```

**Update :**

It should work with this shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -euse File::Basename;exec qq`make -C @{[dirname $ARGV[0]]} -f ` . $ARGV[0]
```

Comment: Well, while it clarifies while my approach does not work, it does not provide a solution either.
I want a solution that works without having to call an external program or script.

Comment: My solution achieves both of the requirements at the beginning of your post (You run directly `/docker/images/Makefile`). `a solution that works without having to call an external program or script` is not in your post.

Comment: This is correct. I did not mention the restriction to the single file, because I did not forsee solutions calling external scripts. Sorry for that :D

Answer (score 0):

What about just:

```
make -C /some/dir/where/there/is/a/makefile
```

Comment: To my understanding, this does not change to /some/dir/where/there/is/a/ before executing the makefile, does it?
And neither allows it to call the makefile as script, as I demanded.

Comment: This is precisely what `-C` or `--directory` is for. So you won't be able to call it like `/some/dir/makefile` as an executable - but calling it like `make -C /some/dir/` (it will automatically pickup any file called `makefile` is effectively equivalent.  I just re-tested this for my sanity and printed `pwd` in a rule and it printed the required directory. It is a suggested alternative, you do not have to accept this answer : )

Comment: Yes, I know that. However I am explicitly searching for a solution, that *will* allow me to start it as an executable, while maintaining the possibility to run `make -C /somedir Makefile`. Anyway, thanks for your input!

Comment: Just one more question - do you need to call the makefile directly as an executable - or would it be acceptable to have an accompanying executable that lives next to your makefile (say called `makefile_exec.sh` or something). This can then determine its own location make sure that is the current directory and then just call `make`... without knowing the precise reason you want your makefile to be executable it is difficult to know, but AFAIK this is again another equivalent method - but weather it suites your specific need I do not know : )

Comment: Yeah, as mentioned in another [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61848450/executable-makefile-that-runs-in-a-specific-directory/61850877?noredirect=1#comment109423635_61849526), I want to be able to call it as executable. And via `make -C`. A bit out of curiosity, a bit because of simpicity on the calling part. And a little bit just because I can.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from similar approaches, I found a solution:

My makefile now has the following head:

```
#!/bin/bash

# the following block will be executed by bash, but not make
define BASH_CODE 2>/dev/null
make -C $(dirname $0) -f $(basename $0) $@
exit 0
endef

# the following lines will be interpreted by make, but not bash

# Makefile starts here #
volumes = $$HOME/docker/volumes

# headings created with https://www.askapache.com/online-tools/figlet-ascii/

default: talk

talk:
    @echo Dies ist ein Test
    pwd

...
```

With these lines in place I can now do the following:

1. call `make -C /path/to/makefile/`
2. call `/path/to/makefile/Makefile`

Anybody with a better solution?

Comment: I will leave this question open for sometime. Maybe someone has a simpler solution, which I would accept.