# Does setting -j8 in MAKEFLAGS cause problems for recursive make?

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, parallel-builds

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475511/set-make-to-always-do-8-jobs-simultaneously) about setting the '-j8' flag globally, and the answer suggested setting `MAKEFLAGS="-j8"` in `/etc/environment`, but they said it could be a problem for recursive make.

However, [GNU documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html) says that `-j8` will be treated in a special way and will not be passed down to recursive invocations of make:

> The ‘-j’ option is a special case (see Parallel Execution). If you set
>   it to some numeric value ‘N’ and your operating system supports it
>   (most any UNIX system will; others typically won't), the parent make
>   and all the sub-makes will communicate to ensure that there are only
>   ‘N’ jobs running at the same time between them all. Note that any job
>   that is marked recursive (see Instead of Executing Recipes) doesn't
>   count against the total jobs (otherwise we could get ‘N’ sub-makes
>   running and have no slots left over for any real work!)

So is setting `MAKEFLAGS="-j8"` in `/etc/environment` problematic or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your operating system supports it, it's not problematic. If for some reason it doesn't, or your make isn't gnu make, it's not a good idea. Also, it's not clear if you execute a program in your make that executes another make, whether or not the two makes will communicate.